# Time zone for PostgreSQL by accessing through client and DBeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have one table in the postgresql database (engine verion 10.11) with a column called resettime which has the datatype as timestamptz. The default timezone for the database is "Australia/Sydney".

The column resettime has the default value as timezone('UTC'::text, now()).

I ran the following command to set this column in DBEaver.

`update mytable set resettime = timezone('UTC', now()) + interval '1 hour' where id = 1;`

The current UTC time is `11:47`, and the corresponding AEST time is `21:47`

After running the above statement, I tried to get the resettime by the following statement in DBEaver.

`select resettime from mytable where id=1`

From this statement, I got `2020-09-14 12:47:25`.

Then, I run the following command in DBEaver.

`update mytable set resettime = resettime + interval '1 hour' where resettime < timezone('UTC', now());`

After run this command, I check the resettime for the record with id=1, I found the resettime was kept as my expectation. It is normal.

However, when I ran the same update statement in my scala application, it updated the resettime as `2020-09-14 13:47:25`. I have a feeling that resettime is still regarded as AEST time if I accessed it through my scala application. I do not want to change the default timezone settings to UTC.

How should I ensure my scala application also get the same behavior as my access through DBEaver? In the above example, I hope the resettime is not changed by my scala application to run the same update statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `timezone('UTC', now())` converts the current timestamp to a `timestamp without time zone` – the result is the current timestamp as it would look on a clock set to UTC time.

Then, when you assign the result to `resettime`, which is a `timestamp with time zone`, the value it converted back, but this time according to your current setting of the `timezome` parameter (which is different from UTC).

So first you ask how a UTC clock looks right now, then you interpret that result in your current time zone. As a consequence, you end up with a value that is offset.

The simple and correct solution is not to convert between the two timestamp types at all, but stick with `timestamp with time zone`:

```
update mytable
set resettime = now() + interval '1 hour'
where id = 1;
```

That will do just what you want.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. It is a very good point. The problem is that my default timezone needs to be AEST. I also need use my scala application to set the initial value for the resettime. My scala application is using UTC timezone, so I can not use now() directly. I also tried the approach to replace timezone('UTC', now()) with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' for all the above commands to make sure the timezone information was kept. However, the same problem still exists.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` _removes_ the time zone information.  I don't see why you can't use now() as it is timestamp with time zone.  Remember, all timestamp with time zone data are stored as UTC and then displayed based upon your session settings.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to teach Scala to do the obvious. But any ORM worth its salt should have a way to do that. If all fails, you can `ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER resettime DEFAULT current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1 hour';` and then `UPDATE mytable SET resettime = DEFAULT WHERE id = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy Laurenz, just give some updates. I changed to use now() in my scala application. It is working.